# How to filter a list according to Slider selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to filter an array of objects according to the user's selection in the `Slider`. But the filter function I'm doing isn't working:

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-feather-3mj64?file=/src/App.js).

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import { dataJobParams } from "./dataJobParams";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const marks = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: "Small"
    },
    {
      value: 33,
      label: "Medium"
    },
    {
      value: 66,
      label: "Large"
    },
    {
      value: 100,
      label: "Extra Large"
    }
  ];

  const onHandleSlider = (value) => {
    const _value = dataParams(value);
    filteredParams(_value);
  };

  const filteredParams = (value) => {
    const filterParams = Object.keys(dataJobParams).filter(
      (el) => el === value
    );

    return filterParams;
  };

  const dataParams = (value) => {
    if (value === 0) {
      const param = "small_data_load";
      return param;
    }

    if (value === 33) {
      const param = "medium_data_load";
      return param;
    }

    if (value === 66) {
      const param = "large_data_load";
      return param;
    }

    if (value === 99) {
      const param = "extra_large_data_load";
      return param;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {console.log("filteredParams: ", filteredParams())}
      <Slider getAriaValueText={onHandleSlider} step={33} marks={marks} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when i use `console.log` inside the `filteredParams`, the result is good.

```
  const filteredParams = (value) => {
    const filterParams = Object.keys(dataJobParams).filter(
      (el) => el === value
    );
    console.log("filteredParams: ", filterParams)
    return filterParams;
  };
```

You have an empty array because you don't use any parameter when you call `{console.log("filteredParams: ", filteredParams())}`

Comment: Hey Nokwiw, but that's return just a string, for example `"extra_large_data_load"`, but I would like that return all the items that contain in the array `extra_large_data_load` in dataJobParams.

Comment: in that case, you `dataJobParams[filterParams]`

`console.log("filteredParams: ", dataJobParams[filterParams])`

Comment: Hey Nokwiw, `dataJobParams[filterParams])`, that way work perfectly for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: let me know if it works.

```js
  const onHandleSlider = (value = "small_data_load") => {
    const _value = dataParams(value);
    const finalValue = filteredParams(_value);
    console.log({ finalValue });
  };

  const filteredParams = (value = "small_data_load") => {
    console.log(value);
    const getValues = Object.entries(dataJobParams);
    const filtredValues = getValues.filter((el) => el[0] === value);
    return {
      name: value,
      values: filtredValues[0][1]
    };
  };
```

Comment: Hey Filipe, but how can I return the items in `medium_data_load` for example?

Comment: @vbernal I edit some code, let me know if works.

Comment: Hew Filipe, that work also, thank you very much.